# Connecting OpenCV 2.4 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV 2.4 with Visual Studio 2015. But I am getting this error while building the project:
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'opencv_world330d.lib' ConsoleApplication3\LINK    1

[image]
I followed all the steps mentioned here:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

Comment: If you're trying to use OpenCV 2.4, then why are you linking with OpenCV 3.3 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your Additional Library Directories, then put opencv_world330.lib to that directories. Otherwise, opencv_world330.lib is library of opencv3.x, with opencv2.4 you must add others library such as opencv_core2412.lib, opencv_highgui2412.lib, etc.

Comment: I already have those additional libararies:
opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_contrib249d.lib
opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_features2d249d.lib
opencv_flann249d.lib
opencv_gpu249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib
opencv_legacy249d.lib
opencv_ml249d.lib
opencv_nonfree249d.lib
opencv_objdetect249d.lib
opencv_ocl249d.lib
opencv_photo249d.lib
opencv_stitching249d.lib
opencv_superres249d.lib
opencv_ts249d.lib
opencv_video249d.lib
opencv_videostab249d.lib
and opencv_world330.lib is not one of them and I am not sure why it is even showing up

Comment: I think you should try opencv3.x instead because winpack version 2.4.x release on opencv website only support for vc12 and vc13

Answer (score -1):

VS can not find your build-opencv library so it throwed that error message.
Maybe there are some space character in your path, something like "C:/Program Files/...". If there aren't, post your full Makefile, compile log.

Comment: Thank you but can you please be more specific, which path?

Comment: This one : "$(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include" and this one : "$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib".

Comment: Thank you, but there is no problem with those paths